# Fresh Red Hat 6.4 kickstarts out-of-date

Tags: redhat, yum, kickstart, satellite, rhn

I am using an updated rhel-x86_64-server-6.4 channel to kickstart RHEL 6.4. What can explain servers being kickstarted with an out-of-date RHEL?

I would like to kickstart the server with the latest packages. It uses the same channel for kickstarting as for updating.

After kickstarting I can type yum update -y, but I would like the systems to be kickstarted up-to-date.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: you can't use the kickstart to immediately be up-to-date, you need to include a `yum update` as port of the post-install.

The kickstart tree is to be accessible for systems that are yet to be deployed and have not been registered yet, in other words it is publicly accessible, where from the commercial point of view the up-to-date channels and updates should only be available for registered systems with valid subscriptions.

Comment: You also have to register the system in `%post` before you can update it.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer to the question is to run `yum update -y` as a post install script.  This is done in the %post section of your kickstart file.  This will ensure the system comes up fully patched.